# Grouping total active users for each of the previous 8 weeks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to generate a report as follow:

```
week-ending date    |   number of active users
8/6/2011                78
8/13/2011               98
8/20/2011               79
```

I have a users table called with these fields

- user_id
- hired_date
- termination_date
- is_active

I also have a date table with the previous 8 weeks which I plan on joining..

- week_start
- week_end
- week_num

I'm stuck in how I can get the active users. How would I group them because I attempted something with datepart and it gave the number of new users within the week (ex. 4 users hired in week7), which isn't what I need. I could use some guidance here. Thanks in advance.

SQL Server 2008

Comment: Safe to assume that for any date, if hired_date is earlier and termination_date is null or later, then the user is active?  In other words, I assume the is_active flag is based on current status and thus not useful for this report?

Comment: Correct, that's a safe assumption

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setup, so we're sure we're talking about the same thing:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.users
(
    [user_id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    hired_date DATE NOT NULL, 
    termination_date DATE
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.[date table]
(
    week_start DATE NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    week_end AS CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, 6, week_start))
);
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO

INSERT dbo.[date table](week_start) VALUES
    ('20110806'),
    ('20110813'),
    ('20110820');

INSERT dbo.users(hired_date, termination_date) VALUES
    ('20110101', NULL), -- long-time, active
    ('20110101', '20110807'), -- long-time, fired in week 1
    ('20110807', '20110815'), -- hired week 1, fired week 2
    ('20110816', '20110816'), -- hired week 2, fired week 2
    ('20110807', '20110825'), -- hired week 1, fired week 3
    ('20110806', NULL), -- hired week 1, active
    ('20110807', NULL), -- hired week 1, active
    ('20110813', NULL), -- hired week 2, active
    ('20110821', NULL); -- hired week 3, active
GO
```

With this logic, there should be 6 active employees during week 1, 7 active employees during week 2, and back down to 6 again in week 3. Took me a few minutes and drawing the active lines on a piece of paper to figure out where I went wrong in my query. Now let's try this one against the sample data we've set up in tempdb:

```
;WITH last_8_weeks AS
(
  SELECT TOP (8) week_start, week_end
    FROM dbo.[date table]
    WHERE week_start >= DATEADD(WEEK, -9, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    ORDER BY week_start DESC
)
SELECT d.week_end, COUNT(u.user_id)
  FROM last_8_weeks AS d
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.users AS u
  ON u.hired_date <= d.week_end 
  AND COALESCE(u.termination_date, DATEADD(DAY, 1, d.week_end)) >= d.week_start
  GROUP BY d.week_end
  ORDER BY d.week_end;
```

And then clean up:

```
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.[date table], dbo.users;
```

Comment: +1 - Would COALESCE or a CASE work better for the current employment check?

Comment: I've made some assumptions here based on @nycdan's comment. If this doesn't get the counts you're looking for, you'll need to better define how you measure whether a user is "active" within a specific week. I've assumed that it means they were active for the WHOLE week. If it means active for any part of that week, you can change AND to OR. I'm also puzzled by the inclusion of is_active in the question. Does the *current* state of that column influence whether the user is included in the results for 8 weeks ago, 7 weeks ago, etc.? That seems to be a state for a specific point in time.

Comment: @JNK could you add a commented-out line to the query to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: added.  This is more of an academic question I guess, but I don't know enough about the internals of `COALESCE` to know if that or `CASE` would be faster

Comment: Aaron,  consider my comment on my answer about partial weeks (term_date > week_start, not week_end).  I think if your query is the right structure, it may need to be modified to account for those.

Comment: Internally `COALESCE` will be translated precisely to the `CASE` structure you provided without having to type it out. As for partial weeks, I do address that in my comment - should be easy enough to change `AND` to `OR` to achieve that functionality (or possibly swap the values as you did in your question - again the requirements are unclear). PS I used an outer join because there may be 0 active users in a given week - unlikely but who knows what the company is like. For example if they cleared out their entire staff 5 weeks ago... :-)

Comment: Sorry...just noticed your comments about partial weeks.  Good point about zero-count rows too.  All good.  Having said that, I'm not sure what's wrong, but i tossed some sample data into these two tables to test mine, and when I ran this one, I got no results back.

Comment: Yep.  Both our queries work and return the same data.  I'm not sure why I got nothing back before, but I used your data setup and it's solid.

Comment: @nycdan There is a slight difference. Assuming `DATE` (or `DATETIME` with midnight / no time), your query - because it uses < and > instead of <= and >= - will miss some rows that happen on the boundary. For example, if you change the 7th user (hired on 08/07) to be hired on 08/12 instead, you no longer include them in week 1.

Answer (score 0):

I was going for something much simpler but I think this will work as well:

```
select top 8 week_end, COUNT(U.user_ID) from users U
join dates D on U.hired_date < D.week_end 
and (U.termination_date > D.week_start or U.termination_date is null)
group by week_end 
order by week_end desc
```

Note that I believe you need to have hired date before the week_end and termination date after the week_start to account for partial weeks.