# Total number of users at end of each week for last 6 months

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find the total number of users at the end of each week for the last 26 weeks.

For example,

- Beginning of week 26 there are 100 users and 20 new users sign up that week so end of week 26 there are 120
- Beginning of week 25 there are 120 users and 20 new users sign up that week so end of week 25 there are 140
- Beginning of week 24 there are 140 users and 0 new users sign up and 10 delete their accounts that week so end of week 24 there are 130
- Beginning of week 23 there are 130 users and 10 new users sign up that week so end of week 24 there are 140

and so on

I can find the number of new users each week but how can I get it to show me the total (i.e. new this week + all those prior to this week) and so on without having to create 26 seperate selects? Is it possible?

I found [Grouping total active users for each of the previous 8 weeks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150904/grouping-total-active-users-for-each-of-the-previous-8-weeks) but it is for SQL Server and I don't think it does quite what I need.

I am using this to get the new each week:

```
select count(id) as total
    from users
    where join_date>='$sixmonths'
    group by WEEK(join_date)
    order by WEEK(join_date) desc
    limit 26
```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT. – and see ROLLUP

Comment: Your query should do the trick. You're getting the total amount of users for each week, that's what you want right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query:

```
select count(u.id) as total,
       (SELECT COUNT(u.id)
        FROM users u2
        WHERE WEEK(u2.join_date) <=
              WEEK(u.join_date)
        AND u2.id = u.id) AS Total_count
from users u
where u.join_date>='$sixmonths'
group by WEEK(u.join_date)
order by WEEK(u.join_date) desc
limit 26
```

For Query to work between years:

```
select count(u.id) as total,
       (SELECT COUNT(u.id)
        FROM users u2
        WHERE YEARWEEK(u2.join_date) <=
              YEARWEEK(u.join_date)
        AND u2.id = u.id) AS Total_count
from users u
where u.join_date>='$sixmonths'
group by YEARWEEK(u.join_date)
order by YEARWEEK(u.join_date) desc
limit 26
```

Comment: This give me "Subquery returns more than 1 row" - do you mean (SELECT COUNT(u2.id) from users u2?

Comment: Just checking back in on this as I have hit a problem - this works great when all the dates are in the same year but, if like now, you have some dates in one year and some in another it seems to break. I get the current data showing me the results from Jan 2014 instead of Jan 2015? In effect it displays as 01/12/14, 08/12/14,15/12/14, 22/12/14, 29/12/14, 05/01/14, 12/01/14, 19/01/14 and so on?

Comment: I'll look later on this problem

Comment: I changed WEEK to YEARWEEK and it seems to have resolved the problem