# Mysql How To Get Total Number Of Registered Users At Each Month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following contacts table

```
id | date_registered
1    2014-08-07
2    2014-08-13
3    2014-08-14
4    2014-10-08
5    2014-10-08
```

I want to run a query which says tell me the number of users that were registered in the months August, September and October.  Hence for the above data the query would return

```
8     3
9     3
10    5
```

This is because 3 people joined in August so until October there are 3 people registered and then another 2 people join making that 5 in October.

I have tried the following query to get the answer (which follows a similar approach to the solution in here [Total number of users at end of each week for last 6 months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19318844/total-number-of-users-at-end-of-each-week-for-last-6-months)).

```
SELECT MONTH(c1.date_registered) AS month, 
     (SELECT COUNT(c2.id)
      FROM contacts AS c2
       WHERE c2.date_registered <= (DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(c1.date_registered,
                                                        INTERVAL 1 MONTH),'%Y-%m-01'))) 
       AS 'contacts on system'
FROM contacts AS c1
WHERE c1.date_registered BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2014-11-01'
GROUP BY MONTH(c1.date_registered)
```

This query returns the following result

```
month | contacts on system
8       3
10      5
```

which is not quite what I want because September is missing from the results.

I have now done what a few people have suggested and used a left join to get september to show.

This is my new query

```
SELECT MONTH(c1.date_registered) AS month, 
     (SELECT COUNT(c2.id)
      FROM contacts AS c2
       WHERE c2.date_registered <= (DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(c1.date_registered,
                                                        INTERVAL 1 MONTH),'%Y-%m-01'))) 
       AS ContactsOnSystem
FROM (select 8 as mon union 
  select 9 as mon union 
  select 10 as mon
 ) as m left join
 contacts as c1
 on  MONTH(c1.date_registered) = m.mon
GROUP BY MONTH(c1.date_registered)
```

When this query is run it returns

```
month |  ContactsONSystem
9        0
8        3
10       5
```

Which is better but still not what I'm after. I want it to say there were 3 contacts on the system for September not 0. The 3 people that registered in August are still registered in September as they haven't gone anywhere.

Got it working at the third attempt

```
SELECT m.mon AS month, (SELECT COUNT(c2.id)
                        FROM contacts AS c2
                        WHERE c2.date_registered < m.monthstart) AS ContactsOnSystem
FROM (select '2014-09-01' as monthstart, 8 as mon union 
      select '2014-10-01' as monthstart, 9 as mon union 
      select '2014-11-01' as monthstart, 10 as mon
 ) as m LEFT JOIN
 contacts as c1
 on  MONTH(c1.date_registered) = m.mon
 GROUP BY MONTH(c1.date_registered)
```

Comment: well, there are no registred users on September in your table, so the output of your query is normal.

Comment: You have to join another table which contains months.(or the first date of each month.)
ex- 2014-08-01, 2014-09-01, 2014-10-01, 2014-11-01, 2014-12-01,....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a full join to a Table containing the months.
Filter to those datasets having the registerdate older than this rows "all-month-list"-date.

You get a list with one entry per user per month since his registration.

Thereover you may group as said before.

Comment: Ah I see what your saying.  Sorry I misunderstood.  Right I'll give that a go.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want by explicitly listing the months and using `left join`:

```
SELECT m.mon AS month, count(c1.date_registered) as ContactsOnSystem
FROM (select 2014 as yr, 8, 201408 as yyyymm as mon union all
      select 2014, 9, 201409 union all
      select 2014, 10, 201410
     ) m left join
     contacts c1
     on yyyymm between year(c1.date_registered) * 100 + month(c1.date_registered)
GROUP BY yyyymm, mon
ORDER B yyyymm;
```

As a note: don't use single quotes for column aliases.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Answer (score 0):

The output of your query is normal because in MySQL you can not display arrows where there are no data. Proof:

```
begueradj@begueradj-X71Q:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 48
Server version: 5.5.40-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> create database SOtest;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use  SOtest;
Database changed
mysql> create table test (id INT, data VARCHAR(10));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)

mysql> insert into test (id, data) values(0,'data0');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> insert into test (id, data) values(1,'data1');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> insert into test (id) values(2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> select * from test where data !='begueradj';
+------+-------+
| id   | data  |
+------+-------+
|    0 | data0 |
|    1 | data1 |
+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

As you can see, the 3rd row is not displayed. It is the normal behavior of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Join your output to a table comtaining the month-numbers with outer join to get 9 | 0 added.

Comment: This is not quite enough.  I have edited my post above to show you why.